# Continuously receiving from a coroutine Channel within an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I'm writing an Android app using Kotlin's coroutines within an Activity. I've got the following declaration of a channel that I can use to receive a stream of notifications, and want to understand how best to perform the related operations on the main (UI) dispatcher:

```
    private var stateNotifications: Channel<Notification>? = null
```

I've presently constructed a `Handler` so that `stateNotifications` can be polled. Its setup looks like this:

```
            stateNotificationHandler.postDelayed(
                handleStateNotifications,
                100L
            )
```

with `handleStateNotifications` declared something like:

```
    private val handleStateNotifications: Runnable = Runnable {
        run {
            val x = when (stateNotifications?.poll()) {
                is ...
            } // FIXME: UPDATE UI
            stateNotificationHandler.postDelayed(
                handleStateNotifications,
                handleStateNotificationsInterval
            )
        }
    }
```

This appears to work. However, I'm thinking that there should be a way to have `stateNotifications` receive on the Default dispatcher and then dispense events to the UI thread. I was thinking something like this:

```
            launch {
                flow<Notification?> {
                    emit(notifications.receive())
                }.onEach { perhaps-invoke-a-handler-to-update-ui }.collect()
            }
```

...but so far, no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

After a good night's sleep, I realised that I needed to continuously receive in a loop using the nice and responsive `flow` based approach e.g.:

```
        job = defaultScope.launch() {
            val notifications = Channel<Handwashing.Notification>()

            launch {
                flow<Notification?> {
                    while (true) {
                        emit(notifications.receive())
                    }
                }.onEach {
                    stateNotificationHandler.postDelayed( {
                        // Do some UI thing
                    },  0)
                }.collect()
            }

            // Push notifications to the notifications channel.
        }
    }
```

Note that having the outer `job` is important for cancelling all coroutines here at a later point when you need to tidy up.